# restore from tar file

Tags: tar

I took a backup using: `cd /usr/CCS`

`tar cvfz /usr/LARGE/BKUP/hms.tar.gz *`

Now I would like to restore `HMS` and overwrite at `/usr/CCS/HMS`.

`HMS` is one of the subfolders under `/usr/CCS`

Can I get some help in restoring only the `HMS` folder from the tar and overwriting it at `/usr/CCS/HMS`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this: `tar -xvf /usr/LARGE/BKUP/hms.tar.gz -C /usr/CCS HMS`

`/usr/LARGE/BKUP/hms.tar.gz` - is your backup

`-C /usr/CCS` - where tar should enter, to start extracting

`HMS` - which files/directorys it should extract from backup (path relative to archived files)

Comment: Thanks, which directory should I cd first.will this work in redhat.

Comment: Directory is irrelevant. `-C` tells tar where to `cd`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much Artur.